# Cannot export Participants - DB Error: unknown error

Tags: export, participants

I choose the Export PRIMARY fields when export a participant, I always get the error "DB Error: unknown error" after click the Continue button at step  2. Export Options.

I open the debug log and got the errors message like the below image. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add detail about the unknown error? You should see the error details down the line or in CiviCRM log

Comment: Does it work if you do not use the Primary Fields option. otherwise you may need the utf8mb4 conversion fix refer https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2784#note_63447
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2780 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21239